# Extracting portion of large string

Tags: python, regex

I'm programming in python, and I'm trying to scrape a website's pagesource. As an example, I'm trying to extract the upc number. This is just portions of the page. There's a bunch of letters, numbers, symbols that surround the upc.

```
myString = someLargeString + '<meta property=og:upc content=02276254215 />' + anotherLargeString
```

I think I can extract it using many splits, but I'm wondering if there's a better way. I learned a bit about using findall, and regular expressions, but I'm unsure if that can be applied here. Would split be the best way to go about this?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is that the only thing you're looking for? If not, you might want to look at [BeautifulSoup](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/beautifulsoup4). Otherwise, a simple regex is probably enough.

Comment: There's a few other things I want to scrape, but this may be useful. Thanks for this. I'll look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A regexp is probably better since it is faster, easier to maintain and easier to read. [Here's](https://developers.google.com/edu/python/regular-expressions?hl=en) a nice tutorial on regexps, which you should probably read if you are going to be doing this website parsing stuff for long.

As an example, if you want to find just one match:

```
import re

m = re.search('upc content=([0-9]*)', string)
if m:
   upc = m.group(1)
   print upc
```

If you are going to reuse the regex, it's probably a good idea to precompile it beforehand as shown [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.compile)

Comment: Incredible. That was a lot simpler than I thought; I was overthinking it too hard. I'll give that link a read. If there may or may not be letters in between the upc numbers, like "02276abc254215" how would we extract everything inside the quote?

Comment: In a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), you can specify all the allowed characters a class can match. So just extend it from `[0-9]` to `[0-9a-z]` or `[0-9a-zA-Z]`.

Comment: I think I understand it now. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

```
import  re

myString = '<meta property=og:upc content=02276254215 />'

print(re.findall(r'upc\s+content=(\d+)',myString))

['02276254215']
```

Answer (score 1):

Another method to Extracting portion of large string, if you know between what strings is in, is using find method of String :

```
myString = '<meta property=og:upc content=02276254215 />'

FirstString = "content="
SecondString = " />"

print(myString[myString.find(FirstString)+len(FirstString)+1:
myString.find(SecondString)])

['02276254215']
```

You can extract a String between FirstString and SecondString.